# Удаление большого числа строк из таблицы Transact-SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql

В общем нужно удалить из таблицы Nodes порядка 110000 записей, только их id указывается не явно а берётся из другой таблицы.

```
DECLARE @gh Table(id int);
INSERT INTO @gh (id) SELECT node_id FROM Relations;
DELETE FROM Nodes WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT id FROM @gh)
```

В `SELECT DISTINCT id FROM @gh` гдето около 20000 записей и в результате удаления не совершаются изза истекшего таймаута.

Answer (score 1):

Зачем такие сложности со временной таблицей? И уж тем более стоит стараться не использовать `IN`.

```
delete t1
from Nodes t1
left join (select distinct node_id from Relations) t2
on t1.id = t2.node_id
where t2.node_id is null
```

Ну и в принципе 100 000 строк это не такое уж и большое количество записей для MSSQL Server.

Comment: Вижу что вопрос старый, но может кому-то пригодится.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте во временную таблицу писать сразу уникальные id (т.е. distinct в insert в том сделайте), потом выведите, что во временной таблице, потом удаляйте из таблицы Nodes.

Comment: И какая субд?